# Python: Unicode to html entities

Tags: python, unicode, encoding, character-encoding

I am having problems converting unicode to html entities.

Here is my current code:

```
>> name = u'\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa1'

>> entities = name.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')

>> print str(entities)
&#195;&#161;&#195;&#161;&#195;&#161;&#195;&#161;
```

Each `\xc3\xa1` = `á` (multibyte character), but when I convert it to entities, I get 2 entities for a single character.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`\xc3\xa1` is `á` in UTF-8, *not* in Unicode.

(`áááá` in Unicode would be `u'\xe1\xe1\xe1\xe1'`)

You therefore need to use a string literal to define it, not an unicode literal (`''` vs `u''`). Once you got UTF-8, you need to decode that to Unicode, in other to encode it again to ASCII with XML entities:

```
>>> name = '\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa1\xc3\xa1'.decode('utf-8')
>>> name.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
'&#225;&#225;&#225;&#225;'
```